# Equivalent of c# class virtual member in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, oop, overriding

So in C# when I've been creating model classes and lazy loading things, I do something like this:

```
public int? User_ID { get; set; }
public int? Dept_ID { get; set; }
```

Then a little farther down in my class I pop in my virtuals like so:

```
public virtual User User {get; set;}
public virtual Department Dept {get; set;}
```

How would I do this in Typescript? Something like this?:

```
User_ID: number;
Dept_ID: number;
User: User;
Dept: Department;
```

I don't think interfaces is what I want/need...but then again protected doesn't seem correct either.  Something tells me I'm missing an obvious answer here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following applies equally to TypeScript and JavaScript:

There is no equivalent.

Every member access in JavaScript is subject to dynamic dispatch by definition. This is because member access in JavaScript is, morally, a key lookup in a hash table.

An object may declare a member with the same key as one it inherits via the prototype chain and thereby *shadow* the inherited member but this is not the same as virtualness, a concept not present in the language.

Comment: That does make sense.  So basically load the extra objects in as I'm doing here and that's about as good as it's going to get.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused by last paragraph. In typescript if I have class A with method M, and class B extends A and also declares method M, then `let x: A = new B(); x.M()` will call B's implementation (even though variable is of type A). That looks like virtual dispatch and not shadowing.

Comment: It shadowing because of how lookup works. Whenever and access is performed, first the object is searched, then the object's prototype, then the prototype's prototype, and so on. Delegation is the basic principle. Note that the type annotation you've applied to the variable will never have any impact on runtime behavior regardless.

Comment: Yes I think I understand that. But in C#, shadowing means that in the above example A's implementation would be called. And observed behavior (no matter the implementation details) would be considered overriding.

Comment: @Evk the thing is in C# the method that gets called depends on the compile time type of the reference and on the declaration (`virtual`/ `override`). In JavaScript none of this matters

Answer (score 15):

Yes there are ..

```
//non-abstract or abstract class
class A {
    
    // The virtual method
    protected virtualStuff1?():void;

    public Stuff2(){
        //Calling overridden child method by parent if implemented
        this.virtualStuff1 && this.virtualStuff1();
        alert("Baseclass Stuff2");
    }
}

//class B implementing virtual method
class B extends A{
    
    // overriding virtual method
    public virtualStuff1()
    {
        alert("Class B virtualStuff1");
    }
}

//Class C not implementing virtual method
class C extends A{
 
}

var b1 = new B();
var c1= new C();
b1.Stuff2();
b1.virtualStuff1();
c1.Stuff2();
```

Comment: I would like to mention that there is the `override` keyword, so you would have `public override virtualStuff1(){ }`

Comment: Also worth mentioning that if you don't provide an implementation in the subclass then `virtualStuff1()` needs to be asserted before being called, or you'll get a `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.` error.

Comment: This answer confuses TypeScript optional `?` with the independent notions of shadowing and  virtual. This means that a function expecting an object with an optional member is yet required to determine if the member exists before accessing it.

Answer (score 3):

All methods in Javascript and Typescript are technically virtual since there's nothing preventing you from being able to override any method.

Comment: unless its private :P

Answer (score -1):

I achieved this using an arrow function as a property of the class (note this was in ts, but if you're handy at modern js it should work):

```
class baseClass {
    doSomething = () => {};
}

class derivedClass extends baseClass {
    constructor() {
        this.doSomeThing = () => { console.log('something'); };
    }
}
```

Comment: This simply doesn't address the question. He's asking how to express virtual members, as in C++ and C#, and the answer is that the languages are fundamentally different from JS and TS which lack a true analog. It's not that the code you offer is incorrect, it's that you didn't address the question