# Inheritance in typescript returns undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-class

I'm, writing the below code, I can't understand how it is working. In C# or Java when we use base or super keyword it returns values but in typescript, I'm getting "undefined". If I use "this" instead of "super" it is working.

```
class Person {
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;

    constructor(fn: string, ln: string) {
        this.firstName = fn;
        this.lastName = ln;
    }
}

class Customer extends Person {

    constructor(fn: string, ln: string) {
        super(fn, ln);
    }

    displayDetails() {
        console.log(`First Name :${super.firstName}\tLast Name :${super.lastName}`);
    }
}

let c = new Customer("Pradeep", "Kumar");
c.displayDetails();
```

could someone explain the execution?

Comment: The best thing to do when learning how to use ecmascript classes, which typescript classes are simply an implementation of, is to throw everything you know about Java and C# classes out the window. Overrides and inheritance work by shadowing in JavaScript.

Comment: You may find this useful in related areas. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50067517/1915893

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See relevant docs at MDN: [super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)

> The super keyword is used to access properties on an **object literal or class's [[Prototype]]**, or invoke a superclass's constructor.
>
> Note that instance fields are set on the instance instead of the constructor's prototype, so you can't use super to access the instance field of a superclass.